# Problemas ao passar um dado de um EditText em um fragment para um TextView em outro fragment

Tags: android

Tenho um *fragment* que contém um *EditText* no qual o usuário irá digitar seu nome.

Em outro *fragment* está o *TextView* que irá receber o nome digitado no *fragment* anterior.

*Fragment* Editar (onde está o usuário digitará o nome):

```
public class Editar extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{ 
    private EditText editar; private Button okBotao;

    View rootview;

    @Nullable 
    @Override 
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_editar, container, false);

        editar = (EditText) rootview.findViewById(R.id.editar); 
        okBotao = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.ok);

        okBotao.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) { 
                InicioActivity menu = new InicioActivity(); 
                Bundle args = new Bundle(); 
                args.putString("editar", String.valueOf(editar));    
                menu.setArguments(args); 
            } 
         }); 
         return rootview;
    }
}
```

*Fragment* Início (onde o nome será exibido):

```
public class Inicio extends Fragment { 
    TextView text; 
    View rootview;

    @Nullable 
    @Override 
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
        rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        TextView text = (TextView)getView().findViewById(R.id.campoNome);
        String editar = getArguments().getString("editar"); 
        text.setText(editar);

        return rootview; 
    }
}
```

Em minha aplicação uso *Navigation Drawer*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está na forma como tenta obter a string do *EditText*.

```
String.valueOf(editar)
```

O método `String.valueOf()` retorna a representação em *string* do valor passado como argumento.
É normalmente usada para converter valores numéricos em *string*.
Quando usada com um *Object*, como é o caso aqui, é o equivalente a chamar o método `object.toString()`.

Normalmente o que `object.toString()` retorna não é o que estamos à espera. Por isso se usar `editar.toString();` não irá obter o texto do *EditText*.

O que está "dentro" de um *EditText* não é uma *string* mas sim um *Editable* que contém o texto introduzido no *EditBox*.
Para aceder a esse texto temos primeiro de obter o *Editable*, usando o método `getText()`, e depois obter a string com `toString()` :

```
editar.getText().toString();
```

Deverá alterar a linha:

```
args.putString("editar", String.valueOf(editar));
```

para

```
args.putString("editar", editar.getText().toString());
```

Comment: Obrigada por me ajudar. Mas a minha aplicação ainda não está dando certo. Essa mensagem de erro é exibida: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity

Comment: No código que postou não vejo nenhum `mTransition` sugiro que faça outra pergunta com o código corrigido e o log de erros.

Comment: O bundle está nulo. Eu encontrei. O código que eu mandei é o que estou usando, a única alteração que fiz foi a que você disse.

Comment: Então o problema é esse. Refira na nova pergunta que ao usar getArguments() este está a retornar null.